# Change the div class if user checked a radio button

Tags: css, vue.js, input

Hi to all i have this two div who has inside a hidden radio button. I want when user click one choise to change the choise-block class with other class. My mind is stucked and i search for possible solutions:

```
             <div class="choise-block">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input visually-hidden" type="radio" @change="choiseCheck">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        <h3>Question 1</h3>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="choise-block">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input visually-hidden" type="radio" @change="choiseCheck">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        <h3>Question 2</h3>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to toggle classes on elements based on some sort of variable value, I'd recommend checking out the [docs on class bindings](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html#binding-html-classes) to get a better grasp on what's possible and how.

But the gist of it is this:

```
<!-- is-active will be toggled when this radio is selected -->
<div class="choise-block" :class="{ 'is-active': picked == 1 }">
  <div class="form-check">
    <input
      class="form-check-input"
      type="radio"
      v-model="picked"
      :value="1"
      id="question-1"
    />
    <label class="form-check-label" for="question-1"> Question 1 </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see it in action in [this codesandbox demo thing](https://codesandbox.io/s/demo-for-stackoverflow-post-gdow9r) I made for ya. Good luck.